# gdal_contour on QGIS can't access the output file

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create contours in QGIS using the SUDEM hisside5 DEM.  (Linux Mint 20.3  3.10.4-A Coruña)  When I run GDAL _contour, I get the following error:

```
2022-09-08T07:30:34     INFO    gdal_contour -b 1 -a ELEV -i 10.0 -f "GPKG" contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png8&layers=pyrbuild:contours_5m_sudem_wc&styles=pyrbuild:contours&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:3857&url=https://sungis08.stb.sun.ac.za/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts? /tmp/contours.gpkg


2022-09-08T07:30:34     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             /bin/sh: 1: /tmp/contours.gpkg: Permission denied
             
             
             
             FAILURE: Missing destination filename.
```

File permissions are set to 666

```
rw-rw-rw- 1 lawrence lawrence 0 Sep  8 07:30 contours.gpkg
```

And directory is accessible:

```
drwxrwxrwt 27 root root 4096 Sep  8 07:30 /tmp
```

Comment: The DEM is a WMS layer? That wont work

Comment: I was using this tutorial.  Can you pojnt me to something better please?

 https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/how-to-create-contour-lines-and-labels-with-qgis/

Comment: In the tutorial linked, there is a link how "to download a similar DEM". Follow these steps and come back when you are stuck, describing what exactly did not work for you.